# GitHub Pages doesn't show Octopress

Tags: github

I have a public GitHub repository for my new Octopress Blog. I just wanted to test some things, so i created a GitHub Page, and linked my Domain to it.

So the domain is now linked to my GitHub Page.

It works fine, and i'm getting the 404 GitHub Error page.

After that, i installed Octopress and pushed it to the Repository. But then... after more than 30 Minutes of waiting... nothing happens. Still the 404 error.

I followed [this](http://www.tomordonez.com/blog/2012/06/04/creating-a-github-blog-using-octopress/) Tutorial and finished it without any errors.

Is it normal to wait so long for GitHub the first time? Or did i miss
something?

Comment: Looks like others in the comments section of that tutorial have experienced the same thing. Maybe you could add a comment there as well.

Answer (score 1):

Other people have [commented on the instructions](http://www.tomordonez.com/blog/2012/06/04/creating-a-github-blog-using-octopress/) that they have had similar problems.  One person found that it was a type on the domain name that caused the problem:

> My name is 2DD847, and for the domain, I thought it doesn't depend on capital or lower letters. Now I changed the repo to capital letters and it works.

Check your domain names and make sure you don't have similar errors.